# href passing multiple parameters using a jquery datatable - render and return

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a working jQuery DataTable that I render 1 query string for each link in a column. The edit, details and delete links of that column each receives the 1 parameter: the 'GbngUpdateId' value that is passed to the corresponding action method as a query string that it in turn uses as needed.

[image]

I now need to add 2 more parameters to the edit link of that column and pass them accordingly in the query string. They would be: 'PublishedSwitch' and 'AlertSentSwitch'.

The 2 extra parameters are in the list of this object that gets sent to the DataTable that it uses to build the grid.

```
 GbngUpdateForMaint gbngUpdateForMaint = new GbngUpdateForMaint
 {
   GbngUpdateId = hold.GbngUpdateId,
   GbngUpdateTitle = hold.GbngUpdateTitle,
   PublishedSwitch = hold.PublishedSwitch,
   PublishedDateTime = hold.PublishedDateTime,
   AlertSentSwitch = hold.AlertSentSwitch,
 };
```

How can I render these 2 extra parameters in the jQuery for that column in the  Datatable?

---

I tried building it - the return string is syntactically correct.

For this column, 'data' refers to: gbngUpdateId.

I don't know how to access 'PublishedSwitch' and 'AlertSentSwitch' which are actually different columns on the same row. I want to use them too and send in the query string for this column.

I have ???? as placeholders for now.

```
 "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
  return '<a href="@Url.Action("EditGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")? 
  gbngUpdateId=' + data + '&publishedSwitch=' + ???? + '&alertSentSwitch=' 
  + ???? +'" class="editGbngUpdate">Edit</a> | <a 
  href="@Url.Action("DetailsGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' 
  + data + '" class="detailsGbngUpdate">Details</a> | <a 
  href="@Url.Action("DeleteGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' 
  + data + '" class="deleteGbngUpdate">Delete</a>';
```

---

Here's the working jQuery DataTable(the grid) that I render 1 query string. The edit, details and delete action methods each receives the 1 parameter: GbngUpdateId value.

```
// Declare the datatable ViewModel.
var gbngUpdateListVM;

$(function () {
    gbngUpdateListVM = {
    dt: null,

    init: function () {
        dt = $('#gbngupdates-data-table').DataTable({
            "serverSide": true,   // For processing server-side.
            "processing": true,   // For showing the progress bar.
            "ajax": {
                "url": "@Url.Action("GetGbngUpdatesForMaintList", "GbngUpdateMaint")",
                "dataType": "json",
                "data": function (data) {
                    },
                "error": function (error) {
                    $("#jsonErrorMessage").text(error.responseJSON.ErrorMessage);
                    // Show it.
                    $("#jsonErrorMessage").css("display", "block");
                }
        },
            "columns": [
                {
                    "title": "Actions",
                    "data": "GbngUpdateId",
                    "searchable": false,
                    "sortable": false,
                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                        return '<a href="@Url.Action("EditGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '" class="editGbngUpdate">Edit</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("DetailsGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '" class="detailsGbngUpdate">Details</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '" class="deleteGbngUpdate">Delete</a>';
                    }
                },
                { "title": "Gbng Update Title", "data": "UpdateTitle", "searchable": true },
                { "title": "Published", "data": "PublishedSwitch", "searchable": true },
                { "title": "Published Date", "data": "PublishedDateTime", "searchable": true },
                { "title": "Alert Sent", "data": "AlertSentSwitch", "searchable": true }
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
            });
        }
    }

    // Initialize the datatable.
    gbngUpdateListVM.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added in 'row' and then used row.ColumnName

```
 "render": function (data, type, row, full, meta) {
 return '<a href="@Url.Action("EditGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + 
 data + '&publishedSwitch=' + row.PublishedSwitch + '&alertSentSwitch=' + 
 row.AlertSentSwitch + '" class="editGbngUpdate">Edit</a> | <a 
 href="@Url.Action("DetailsGbngUpdate", "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '" 
 class="detailsGbngUpdate">Details</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteGbngUpdate", 
 "GbngUpdateMaint")?gbngUpdateId=' + data + '&publishedSwitch=' + row.PublishedSwitch 
 + '&alertSentSwitch=' + row.AlertSentSwitch +'" class="deleteGbngUpdate">Delete</a>';
```